# Eventlistener not adding to a object -JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that get some info from a database and then changes the innerHTML based on that information. this function also puts eventlisteners into the HTML objects so i can use them. The problem is that the eventlistener won't apply on the object.

```
async function getGamesFromCard() {
  const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/cart/games`);
  const items = await response.json();

  const gamesFromCard = items[0];
  const infoFromCart = items[1];

  const cart = document.getElementById(`cartList`);
  let innerHTML;
  for (let i = 0; i < infoFromCart.length; i++) {
    const price = infoFromCart[i].quantity * gamesFromCard[i].price;
    totalPrice += price;

    innerHTML += `<li>
        <span>${gamesFromCard[i].name}</span>
        <input
        type="number"
        min="1"
        max="99"
        value="${infoFromCart[i].quantity}"
        id="changeQuantityGame${i}"
        />
        <span class="price">${price.toFixed(2)}</span>
        <button class="removeButton" id="removeGame${i}">
          Remove
        </button>
      </li>`;
  }
  cart.innerHTML = innerHTML;

  for (let i = 0; i < infoFromCart.length; i++) {
    const removeButton = document.getElementById(`removeGame${i}`);
    removeButton.addEventListener("click", () =>
      deleteItemFromCart(infoFromCart[i].id)
    );

    const quantityButton = document.getElementById(`changeQuantityGame${i}`);
    quantityButton.addEventListener("change", () => {
      const quantity = parseInt(quantityButton.value);
      updateQuantity(infoFromCart[i], quantity);
    });
  }
}
```

i have tried to find the problem with some `console.log()` statements and came to the conclusion that the eventlistener doesn't work or isn't added on the object. I don't get anny erros but the buttons just don't work.
Here is the hole code:

```
let totalPrice = 0.0;

async function getGamesFromCard() {
  const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/cart/games`);
  const items = await response.json();

  const gamesFromCard = items[0];
  const infoFromCart = items[1];

  const cart = document.getElementById(`cartList`);
  let innerHTML;
  for (let i = 0; i < infoFromCart.length; i++) {
    const price = infoFromCart[i].quantity * gamesFromCard[i].price;
    totalPrice += price;

    innerHTML += `<li>
        <span>${gamesFromCard[i].name}</span>
        <input
        type="number"
        min="1"
        max="99"
        value="${infoFromCart[i].quantity}"
        id="changeQuantityGame${i}"
        />
        <span class="price">${price.toFixed(2)}</span>
        <button class="removeButton" id="removeGame${i}">
          Remove
        </button>
      </li>`;
  }
  cart.innerHTML = innerHTML;

  for (let i = 0; i < infoFromCart.length; i++) {
    const removeButton = document.getElementById(`removeGame${i}`);
    removeButton.addEventListener("click", () =>
      deleteItemFromCart(infoFromCart[i].id)
    );

    const quantityButton = document.getElementById(`changeQuantityGame${i}`);
    quantityButton.addEventListener("change", () => {
      const quantity = parseInt(quantityButton.value);
      updateQuantity(infoFromCart[i], quantity);
    });
  }
}

async function getDlcsFromCard() {
  const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/cart/dlcs`);
  const items = await response.json();

  const dlcsFromCard = items[0];
  const infoFromCart = items[1];
  console.log(infoFromCart);

  const cart = document.getElementById(`cartList`);
  let innerHTML = cart.innerHTML;
  for (let i = 0; i < infoFromCart.length; i++) {
    const price = infoFromCart[i].quantity * dlcsFromCard[i].price;
    totalPrice += price;

    innerHTML += `<li>
          <span>${dlcsFromCard[i].name}</span>
          <input
          type="number"
          min="1"
          max="99"
          value="${infoFromCart[i].quantity}"
          id="changeQuantityDlc${i}"
          />
          <span class="price">${price.toFixed(2)}</span>
          <button class="removeButton" id="removeDlc${i}">
            Remove
          </button>
        </li>`;
  }
  cart.innerHTML = innerHTML;

  for (let i = 0; i < infoFromCart.length; i++) {
    const removeButton = document.getElementById(`removeDlc${i}`);
    removeButton.addEventListener("click", () =>
      deleteItemFromCart(infoFromCart[i])
    );

    const quantityButton = document.getElementById(`changeQuantityDlc${i}`);
    quantityButton.addEventListener("change", () => {
      const quantity = parseInt(quantityButton.value);
      updateQuantity(infoFromCart[i], quantity);
    });
  }
}

async function loadItemsFromCard() {
  const response1 = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/cart/games`);
  const response2 = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/cart/dlcs`);

  const games = await response1.json();
  const dlcs = await response2.json();

  const gamesEmpty = games[0].length == 0 && games[1].length == 0;
  const dlcsEmpty = dlcs[0].length == 0 && dlcs[1].length == 0;

  if (!gamesEmpty || !dlcsEmpty) {
    getGamesFromCard();
    getDlcsFromCard();
    await Promise.all([getGamesFromCard(), getDlcsFromCard()]);
    const totalPriceSpan = document.getElementById("totalPrice");
    totalPrice = totalPrice / 2;
    totalPriceSpan.textContent = `€${totalPrice.toFixed(2)}`;
  } else {
    const cartList = document.getElementById(`cartList`);
    cartList.innerHTML = `<span>Cart is empty</span>`;
    const totalPriceSpan = document.getElementById("totalPrice");
    totalPriceSpan.textContent = `€0.00`;
  }
}

async function deleteItemFromCart(item) {
  console.log(item);
  const id = item.id;
  const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/cart/${id}/remove`, {
    method: "DELETE",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
  totalPrice = 0.0;
  await loadItemsFromCard();
}

async function updateQuantity(item, quantity) {
  const id = item.id;
  if (isNaN(quantity)) {
    deleteItemFromCart(id);
  } else {
    const response = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:5000/api/cart/${id}/${quantity}`,
      {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
  }
  loadItemsFromCard();
}

async function deleteItemFromCart1(item) {
  console.log(item);
}

loadItemsFromCard();
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/). Attach both a click and change listener to the `ul` element and have those deal with the necessary processing. [Data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) might be a good way to identify the ids of the list items, too.